# How can i know if current time is 5 am in specific time zone

Tags: java, datetime

My system time zone is utc.
How can I know using java date time api if its 5am in a given timezone?

How can I use zone date time for this?

Is it 5am in singapore now?
Is it 5am in india now?
Is it 5am in austria now?

Thanks

This is my final logic. After working on the solutions below.

```
    public class MorningReminderScheduler {

    @Scheduled( cron="0 0/5 * * * *  ")
    public static void main(String args[]){
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        for (String zoneId : ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()) {
            ZoneId z = ZoneId.of(zoneId);
            // LocalDateTime -> ZonedDateTime
            LocalTime l= LocalTime.now(z);
            if(l.getHour()==5 && l.getMinute()<5){
                System.out.println("its between 5 hour to 5 hour 5 min in  = " + z.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want a tolerance of, say, 10 milliseconds or half a minute? You’d be so unlikely to hit 5 AM with microsecond precision that I’d say the answer will be “no” every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean `5:00` when you say `5 am` i.e. you are not considering the seconds and nanoseconds, you can compare the hour and minute of time at Singapore with `5` and `0` respectively to evaluate if it is `5 am`.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Singapore has the Zone Offset of UTC +8
        LocalTime nowAtSingapore = OffsetTime.now().withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(8)).toLocalTime();
        System.out.println("Now at Singapore: " + nowAtSingapore);
        System.out.println("Now (HH:mm) at Singapore: " + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm").format(nowAtSingapore));

        // Check if it is 5:00 at Singapore now
        if (nowAtSingapore.getHour() == 5 && nowAtSingapore.getMinute() == 0) {
            System.out.println("It's 5:00 at Singapore");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Now at Singapore: 05:24:43.217733
Now (HH:mm) at Singapore: 05:24
```

**Note:** that the default format of `LocalTime.toString()` is `HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS` where `SSSSSS` denotes nanoseconds. In order to get a string in a custom pattern, we use [`DateTimeFormatter#ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I will try this.

Comment: @MukeshKatariya It’s unreadable in the comment. It should work. I’d prefer to use the methods `isBefore`  and/or `isAfter` for checking whether the time is within the desired interval.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the LocalTime class to find the local time in any support time zone. For example:

```
String zoneId = "Asia/Singapore";
LocalTime timeInSingapore = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of(zoneId));
```

To find if it's 5 am in Singapore, you'll probably want to apply some threshold because the time is exactly 5 am for a very short period of time. What you could do is calculate the difference between 5 am and the given moment in time, and if the difference is "small enough" you can claim it's 5 am. For example, this will claim the time is 5am at any time between 4:50 and 5:10:

```
LocalTime fiveAm = LocalTime.of(5, 0);
long minutesBetween = Math.abs(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(fiveAm, timeInSingapore));
if (minutesBetween <= 10) {
    // close enough
    System.out.println("It's 5am in " + zoneId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I will try this.

Comment: So let say if I have a CRON job which runs every 5 minutes, to track if its 5 am in a set of given zones. So if its 5 am in Singapore. SMS each employee of Singapore #no of appointments for the day. If its 5 am in India. SMS each employee of India.

So whenever the job is triggered. I need to check the minutes between if it's within threshold. why have we taken Math.abs ? will it be good without it ?

Comment: If you can use cron, why not just schedule the jobs so that Singapore messages get sent set at 5am Singapore time, and same for India? Instead of one single job that runs every 5 minutes

Comment: The difference between 5am and 4am is 60 minutes, the difference between 5am and 6am is -60 minutes. Math.abs gives you the absolute value of the difference: 60 for both 4am and 6am

Comment: I have users/employees from different time zones.

Comment: Yes and I'm suggesting you schedule separate daily jobs for each time zone instead of one job that runs every 5 minutes and tries to decide which time zone to use. It'll be easier to control which users are supposed to processed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zoneId of the timezone you want to know the time of. Format the date using a DateFormatter and then verify if it's 5:00 AM. A sample code can be like below:

```
public static void getCurrentTimeWithTimeZone(){
    System.out.println("-----Current time of a different time zone using LocalTime-----");
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
    LocalTime localTime=LocalTime.now(zoneId);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedTime=localTime.format(formatter);
    System.out.println("Current time of the day in Los Angeles: " + formattedTime);
    if(formattedTime.equals("05:00:00")
       System.out.println("It is 5 AM in Los Angeles");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** For your cron job I suggest you keep track of the last date you sent the text (SMS) message for that time zone. So if it is now past 5 AM *on the following day*, send the next message (and update the date stored). This will make sure that the message is sent even if the job doesn’t happen to run exactly within your 5 minutes tolerance interval. Also it will not be sent twice if the job happens to run twice. Time is tricky in that we never get things to happen exactly at the time specified, so we have to take these possibilities into account.

**Original answer**

No, it is not 5 AM in India or one of the other time zones you mentioned. The point in time of 5 AM in some time zone lasts 0, so the probability that it is that time is 0.

On many platforms Java can since Java 9 read the time with microsecond precision. So even though it *is* not exactly 5 AM, it leaves us with a probability of 0.000000001 % that the time read is 5 AM. It’s still minute enough to say that it will practically never happen.

So I suggest that you work with some tolerance: If the time is sufficiently close to 5 AM, you regard it as 5 AM. For example:

```
    final LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(5, 0); // 5 AM
    final Duration tolerance = Duration.ofMillis(600); // 0.6 seconds as an example
    
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"); // India
    
    LocalTime nowInZone = LocalTime.now(zone);
    if (nowInZone.isBefore(time.minus(tolerance)) || nowInZone.isAfter(time.plus(tolerance))) {
        System.out.println("No, it is not " + time + " in " + zone);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Yes, it is " + nowInZone + " in " + zone);
    }
```

When I ran the code just now, output was the likely:

> No, it is not 05:00 in Asia/Kolkata

Beware that the code only works correctly so long as the tolerance doesn’t cross midnight (12 AM). For example, it the time was 0:01 AM and the tolerance was 2 minutes, we’d check whether the time was after 23:59 *and* before 0:03. No time can be both, so we’d always get *No* even if the time was within that 4 minutes gap. But for 5 AM and a tolerance less than 5 hours it does work.

Comment: Agree, will make it more robust.